# view is distorted after implementing grappelli

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I have applied Grappeli in my django admin.when i applied ,it working successfully but my view is distorted. firstly the main heading "Django site administration" is not visible and all row and column distorted(shifted from their original position). i want to arrange row and column.
**my settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli.dashboard',
    'grappelli',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'account',
    # 'search',
    'lead',
    'import_export',
    'webcam',
    'debug_toolbar',
    # 'apptemplates.Loader',
    'webcam.tests',
    # 'data_exports',
    # 'localflavor',
```

Please help me.i attached my Django admin site image below
[image]

Comment: you Should add your model filed in list_display properly...... what does mean by view distorted can u elaborate it

Comment: i have attached the picture

Comment: i want the field in arranged manner...

Comment: @MushahidKhan can you please help me in this